# Intermittent "Pool wait interrupted. java.sql.SQLException: Pool wait interrupted." Java server connecting to Mysql

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat, configuration

I've not found any good information about what "Pool wait interrupted" means.  I'm attempting to connect from Tomcat (6 at the moment, upgrading to 8 soon) to MySql 5.6 and generally all works fine.  Over the past year we've gone through two periods of time (about two weeks long or so) where this error:

> Pool wait interrupted. java.sql.SQLException: Pool wait interrupted.

appears at least once per day.  The server application is a read-only application where fast request-time performance is essential.

Here's my Connector/J configuration information:

```
<Resource 
name="connectionJNDIName"
auth="Container"
type="javax.sql.DataSource"
factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory"

testOnBorrow="true"
testOnReturn="false"
validationQuery="SELECT 1"
validationInterval="30000"

initialSize="10"
maxActive="100"
maxIdle="50"
minIdle="10"

suspectTimeout="60"
timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis="30000"
minEvictableIdleTimeMillis="60000"

removeAbandoned="true"
removeAbandonedTimeout="60"
logAbandoned="true"

testWhileIdle="true"
maxWait="10000"

jmxEnabled="true"
jdbcInterceptors="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.ConnectionState;org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.StatementFinalizer"
username="username"
password="password123"
driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"

url="<databaseConnectionURL>"/>
```

Because the application works so much of the time, I don't think the problem is caused in the server app itself, but I would like to be more resilient.  The DBA team tells me that the MySql server is clean (when they get to it to check), but the server is not returning data as it should even so.  I looked at setting `autoReconnectForPools='true'` but have read documentation indicating some concerns about using that -- and I don't know that would solve the issue in any case.